# zeros of a certain vector field in $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$

Tags: differential-geometry, projective-space

Let's consider the complex projective space $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ and let $X$ be a vector field with flow given by $X_{t}:\mathbb{C}P^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ such that $X_{t}([z_{0},...,z_{n}])=[z_{0},\exp(it)z_{1},...,\exp(int)z_{n}]$.

In order to apply Poincaré-Hopf Theorem and conclude that $\chi(\mathbb{C}P^{n})=n+1$, I would like to prove that $X$ has exactly $n+1$ zeros with index $1$.
How can I do this ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

At a point $z=(z_0,\cdots,z_n)\in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$, The natural projection maps vectors like $\lambda z$ to a zero vector of $\mathbb{C}P^n$. So to find the zeros just ask $$\frac{dX_t}{dt}|_{t=0}=(0, iz_1,\cdots,inz_n)=\lambda(z_0,\cdots,z_n)$$ we get 
$$ikz_k=\lambda z_k, \forall k=0,\cdots, n$$
So the zeros of $X$ are the following points (setting $\lambda=0,i,2i,\cdots,ni$):
$$[1,0,0,\cdots,0]$$
$$[0,1,0,\cdots,0]$$
$$\cdots$$
$$[0,0,0,\cdots,1]$$
To compute the index of a zero point, e.g. $[1,0,\cdots,0]$, use the coordinate chart $[z_0,\cdots, z_n] \mapsto (z_1/z_0,\cdots, z_n/z_0)$, the flow is $$X_t(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=(\exp(it)x_1,\cdots,\exp(int)x_n)$$ And the vector field is $$X(x_1,\cdots,x_n)=i(x_1,2x_2,\cdots,nx_n)$$ This map is obviously 1 to 1 and orientation preserving when restricting to a small sphere around 0, that is, $X$ has index 1 at 0.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain me what do you mean with zero vector of $\mathbb{C}P^{n}$ ? The lines where you compute the zeros of $X$ are not clear for me. Why can I take $\lambda = 0$ ? I guess it is just me confused with notation and my lack of experience dealing with projective spaces, so I appreciate you patience with me and with this stupid question. Thank you again :)

Comment: Basically, my whole problem with this, was always with computing the zeros of $X$, since I really get confused with the notation. Thanks again, Xipan.

Comment: Any points $[z_0, \cdots, z_n]$ that satisfy the equation $ikz_k=\lambda z_k$ for some $\lambda$ is a zero point of X. Since $\lambda z_0=i 0 z_0=0$ this implies either $\lambda=0$ or $z_0=0$